# Tunnel Failed at the time of Upload file to FTP

Tags: blackberry-jde

File upload is works fine from my simulator (blackberry 8830).It upload the file to FTP Server. But in the device when I try to upload file to FTP server it gives the alert “Tunnel Failed “.

I am using 
StreamConnection sc = (StreamConnection) Connector.open(url);

How to solve this issue. Can anyone help me???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simulator uses the network of the host machine, while the device goes through an internal RIM proxy.  Are you using passive ftp?  You might have better luck with HTTP POST since you cannot establish a direct connection on the device.